# Check logs for a Kubernetes resource CronJob

Tags: kubernetes

I created a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) resource in Kubernetes.

I want to check the logs to validate that my crons are run. But not able to find any way to do that. I have gone through the [commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs) but looks like all are for pod resource type.

Also tried following

```sh
$ kubectl logs cronjob/<resource_name>
error: cannot get the logs from *v1beta1.CronJob: selector for *v1beta1.CronJob not implemented
```

Questions:

1. How to check logs of CronJob Resource type?
2. If I want this resource to be in specific namespace, how to implement that same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the logs of the pods which are created by the cronjob. The pods will be in completed state but you can check logs.

```
# here  you can get the pod_name from the stdout of the cmd `kubectl get pods`
$ kubectl logs -f -n default <pod_name>
```

For creating a cronjob in a `namespace` just add namespace in `metadata` section. The pods will created in that `namespace`.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: default
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Ideally you should be sending the logs to a log aggregator system such as ELK or Splunk.

Comment: thanks a lot @Arghya Sadhu, able to check the logs now and they are running fine. Just one more question, if want to create CronJob in specific namespace. How to achieve that ?

Comment: as specified in the answer..add namespace in the metadata

Comment: got it. Thanks a lot @Ardhya Sadhu, all resolved now :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you create job from cronjob it works like this:
kubectl -n "namespace" logs  jobs.batch/<resource_name> --tail 4