# How to verify a cronjob successfully completed in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I am trying to create a cronjob that runs the command **date** in a single busybox container. The command should run every minute and must complete within 17 seconds or be terminated by Kubernetes. The cronjob name and container name should both be hello.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      name: hello
    spec:
      completions: 1
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 17
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: busybox
            name: hello
            command: ["/bin/sh","-c","date"]
            resources: {}
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
  schedule: '*/1 * * * *'
status: {}
```

I want to verify that the job executed successfully at least once.
I tried it using the command **k get cronjob -w** which gives me this result.

[image]

Is there another way to verify that the job executes successfully? Is it a good way to add a command **date** to the container?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`CronJob` internally creates `Job` which internally creates `Pod`. Watch for the job that gets created by the `CronJob`

```
kubectl get jobs --watch
```

The output is similar to this:

```
NAME               COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
hello-4111706356   0/1                      0s
hello-4111706356   0/1           0s         0s
hello-4111706356   1/1           5s         5s
```

And you can see the number of `COMPLETIONS`

```
#Replace "hello-4111706356" with the job name in your system

pods=$(kubectl get pods --selector=job-name=hello-4111706356 --output=jsonpath={.items[*].metadata.name})
```

Check the pod logs

```
kubectl logs $pods
```

Comment: The strange thing is that the pod has status RunContainerError.

Comment: then it did not run properly..check by describing the pod and logs of the pod

Comment: I checked the logs and see this message => Error: failed to start container "hello": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bins/sh\": stat /bins/sh: nosuch file or directory": unknown

Comment: I tried it in browser where it obviously does not work but in my terminal it works good. Thank you for help.

Comment: sure..if you face any further issue I suggest to ask a new question with error logs

Answer (score 2):

you can check the logs of the pods created by the cronjob resource. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591704/check-logs-for-a-kubernetes-resource-cronjob) and let me know if this solves your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly check the status of the jobs. Cronjob is just controlling a Kubernetes job.

Run `kubectl get jobs` and it will give you the completion status.

```
> kubectl get jobs
NAME           COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
datee-job      0/1 of 3      24m        24m
```